# Unit Testing data from DB2

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, transactions, db2

I have a .NET project (Test project) in VS2008 and am doing some unit tests for the data in DB2. I am finding that the tests are not transactional and I have to phyiscally go and delete the data or run a function to clean the data before I run the test even though I am using ITransaction. Can any one point why?

Comment: Please use 'visualstudio2008' rather than 'vs2008'. Watch the suggestions when tagging your questions: in this case 'visualstudio2008' is used on the site over 2000 times while vs2008 is used < 100.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the .net environment. The default is commit and if you do not want to save the changes, you would have to explicitly rollback the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to DB2 check to make sure that "auto-commit" is not set to true